# can I use ATF IV instead of Dexron for 2005 toyota camry

Tags: toyota, camry

The manual states Dexron or Dexron II to use for power steering fluid. ATF IV is listed on the manual for transmission oil. Can I use that instead of Dexron/Dexron II? Can I mix it with the Dexron already in the car?
The only other options I have are Dexron III or Lucas oil, which states it is universal for all cars but I am skeptical about that.

Comment: Any later generation of Dexron is safe to use in older equipment designed for DX, DXII, or III

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ATF IV and Dexron II are different enough I'd suggest against using it, however all Dexron fluids are backwards compatible, so you could use Dexron III or Dexron VI. If you can get Dexron III you can mix it with the exiting Dexron II in your power steering reservoir without issue.

If you're refilling it then there's a leak somewhere, you may want to have that looked at.

Answer (score 2):

A "universal" fluid that is commonly available is labeled "Dex/Merc" and are usually compatible with Mercon (not Mercon V), Dexron II, and Dexron III, and possibly others. I would not use ATF+4 since it is a different formulation meant for Chrysler transmissions. Dex/Merc fluid is easy to find and also cheap.

Dexron VI is a superior fluid that is backwards compatible. It could also be used, but it is more expensive.

That being said, would ATF+4 work? In a power steering pump, it would "probably" be OK, since a power steering system is much less demanding on the fluid than an automatic transmission. In an automatic transmission, ATF serves as coolant and lubricant, has to resist high shear forces and temperatures, and must keep debris and contaminants suspended for long periods of time. A power steering pump basically just needs a light hydraulic oil. But the risk in this case is not worth it, IMO.